# mvc 4 razor view do not understand @Html.Kendo()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am facing one problem with Kendo UI server wrappers in ASP.NET MVC 4
If I use .ASPX default view It understands the

```
 <%: Html.Kendo().Grid() %>
```

But at the same time If I try to add Razor view
It do not understand

```
 @(Html.Kendo() ) systax.
```

I have entry in web.config as well

```
<namespaces>
<add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />


<httpHandlers>
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false" />
  </httpHandlers>

 <handlers>
  <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd"  type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" />
```

Pl tell me what I must be missing and where

Thanks and Regards,

Amit

Comment: Are you getting an exception or is it just visual studio intelli-sense not working?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To register Kendo UI using Razor templates make sure you have the below in your Views\Web.config.

Towards the bottom of the page also details the setup in telerik's documentation.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-4

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory,
          System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
          PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            ...
            <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc"/>
            <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI"/>
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

I also have the below in my main Web.config file.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
        <assemblies>
           ...
            <add assembly="Kendo.Mvc"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

Comment: already had the <system.web.webPages.razor> tag but Kendo namespaces were not there..just added...SOLVED...THANKS

Answer (score 10):

Adding `@using Kendo.Mvc.UI` at the top of the page and it worked for me

Comment: @ChuckKrutsinger - I added it to my view.

Answer (score 4):

Check if your **web.config** settings is in the **View Folder** ( web.config files) not the root Web.config